# How to block Facebook app and facebook.com from loading on an iOS device

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

On a Windows or Mac computer, I'd edit the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1     facebook.com
127.0.0.1     www.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   www.login.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1   www.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1   fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1   www.fbcdn.com
127.0.0.1   static.ak.fbcdn.net
127.0.0.1   static.ak.connect.facebook.com
127.0.0.1   connect.facebook.net
127.0.0.1   www.connect.facebook.net
127.0.0.1   apps.facebook.com


# Block Facebook IPv6
#fe80::1%lo0     localhost
::1     facebook.com
::1     www.facebook.com
::1     login.facebook.com
::1     www.login.facebook.com
::1     fbcdn.net
::1     www.fbcdn.net
::1     fbcdn.com
::1     www.fbcdn.com
::1     static.ak.fbcdn.net
::1     static.ak.connect.facebook.com
::1     connect.facebook.net
::1     www.connect.facebook.net
::1     apps.facebook.com
::1     edge-star6-shv-02-ams2.facebook.com
```

How would I do this on an iOS device (not jailbroken). Can I do this with a provisioning profile?

Comment: There are two kinds of net connections available iOS devices, those with wifi and cellular, and those with just wifi. Are you asking how to block for _both_ types of connections?

Comment: Well Cellular or WiFi iPads can only be updated 1 way. If you're on Cellular, the firmware does NOT download. If you won't use WiFi then you have to connect to a  Mac/PC with USB. This is great for consumers who only have 1 or 2 iPads. But organizations have more than 30 will be difficult

Answer (score 2):

Not directly, but you could use a provisioning profile to assign a web proxy or custom DNS server to perform your filtering.

Comment: I can setup a Proxy Server at home so when it's on my WiFi, FaceBook is blocked or redirected to another site. However when the connection uses Cellular, my proxy servers won't really do anything.

Comment: @softwareisfun yep - a VPN to your home proxy would be needed for cellular protection.

Comment: I have no idea how to even start setting up VPN to my Home network using OS X Server. Nor do I know how slow the Internet could become if we did this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use safari plugins to help you blocking URL's, like 1Blocker and use the 'Block URL's function.

[image: 1Blocker]

*BTW, another way would be to use a custom DNS server.*

Comment: Blocking it here maybe a good idea but the End user can easily unblock. If there was an App that required authentication to change settings, that would be really good

Comment: This doesn't work with iPhone 5! It says it needs iPhone 5s! WTF? They both have iOS 9.

Comment: @Chloe, ^ and therefor a downvote?